# R : Sort the list of instances of a class based on an attribute in R

Tags: r, class, sorting

I have created a class to keep a set of records (say matrix and average) in an instance as follows.

```
setClass("Individual", representation(mymat= "matrix", average= "numeric"))
```

Then, since I have list of matrices, I created a list of instance in above class and stores each values as bellow. I have list of "thematrix" already.

```
 each_individual<-list()
for(i in 1:p)
 { 
  each_individual[[p]]<- new("Individual", mymat=thematrix[[p]], average=avg)
 }
```

Here, "each_individual" keeps all the instances of matrix and its average. Now If I want to order the "each_individual" list based of "average" parameter, How can I do it on R. In other words, how can I rank this instance.